# java 8 Springboot How to use properties from application.yml file in annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-annotations, spring-retry

I am using java 8, Spring boot 2.2 and have a piece of code where I use `@Retryable`. The backoff, maxattempt fields as of now are hardcoded and I wish to make them configurable. But only constants are allowed in there; have to be final. Any idea on how to overcome this ? I remember seeing some code somewhere which makes me think its possible. I know I can do it via `RetryTemplate`. But I cant digest the idea that there is no other way.
I want this.

```
@Retryable( value = { SQLException.class },maxAttempts = 2,backoff =
@Backoff(delay = 5000))
```

I to become something like this

```
@Retryable( value = { SQLException.class },maxAttempts =
"${applicationyml['myproperty']}",backoff = @Backoff(delay =
"${applicationyml['myproperty']}"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `maxAttemptsExpression` etc;

They can get property placeholders `${some.property}` where `some.property` is in the YAML, or SpEL expressions

`#{@someBean.someProperty}`

Example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/71744ee8cbe7cfd03e446e2aaa91b4a494edf09f/src/test/java/org/springframework/retry/annotation/EnableRetryTests.java#L550-L553).

```java
@Retryable(exceptionExpression = "#{@exceptionChecker.${retryMethod}(#root)}",
        maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@integerFiveBean}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${one}}",
                maxDelayExpression = "#{${five}}", multiplierExpression = "#{${onePointOne}}"))
public void service3() {
    ...
}
```